# Bitmaps breaking up on android when using createjs and canvas

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-canvas, createjs

This isn't as much of a code question as it is a performance question. I'm making a small game that's meant to work both on a desktop browser as well as in a mobile. I'm making the game using HTML5 and CreateJs and drawing most of it on a canvas.

My problem is that it all works great on a standard desktop browser but once I run it through PhoneGap on my android device I get weird glitches in the graphics. If I remove something from the canvas in the most basic of ways, like this:

```
stage.removeChild(myBitmap);
stage.update();
```

**then sometimes, not everytime, part of the bitmap is still left on the canvas. I would say about 10% of it stays left there.** It feels as though I need to flush or redraw the canvas. Is there a known problem with canvas on android (I have only seen it happen on android) or is this a createjs related problem?

The same problem occurs if I move the bitmap with an animation.

Comment: Definitely Android related. Android's canvas (particularly the one in the non-Chrome Browser) is one of the most problematic canvas implementations, and has lots of issues like this, not to mention poor performance.

Comment: I haven't had too much to complain about performance wise, but I'm not drawing that intensively. This, however, is a fairly enormous bug. Not being able to move a bitmap or remove it from the canvas sort of makes it pointless :)

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, its a bug in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. This is a known android 4.1+ error that seems to happen mainly in Samsung (S2+) devices. Read more about the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39247.

In short, the following code solved my problem:

```
stage.update();
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.style.opacity = 0.99;
setTimeout(function() 
{
    canvas.style.opacity = 1;
}, 1);
```

**So it is not a PhoneGap or CreateJS problem!**